# Linq left outer group by, then left outer the group

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I've this query that i'm trying to put as linq:

```
select * 
from stuff
inner join stuffowner so on so.stuffID = stuff.stuffID
left outer join (select  min(loanId) as loanId, stuffownerId from loan  
 where userid = 1 and status <> 2 group by stuffownerId) t on t.stuffownerid = so.stuffownerid
left outer join loan on t.LoanId = loan.LoanId
```

when this is done, I would like to do a linq Group by to have Stuff has key, then stuffowners + Loan as value.

I can't seem to get to a nice query without sub query (hence the double left outer).

So basically what my query does, is for each stuff I've in my database, bring the owners, and then i want to bring the  first loan a user has made on that stuff.

I've tried various linq:

```
from stuff in Stuffs
join so in StuffOwners on stuff.StuffId equals so.StuffId
join  tLoan in Loans on so.StuffOwnerId equals tLoan.StuffOwnerId into tmpJoin 
from tTmpJoin in tmpJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
group tTmpJoin by new {stuff}  into grouped
select new {grouped, fluk = (int?)grouped.Max(w=> w.Status )}
```

This is not good because if I don't get stuff owner and on top of that it seems to generate a lot of queries (LinqPad)

```
from stuff in Stuffs
join so in StuffOwners on stuff.StuffId equals so.StuffId
join tmpLoan in 
 (from tLoan in Loans group tLoan by  tLoan.StuffOwnerId into g 
 select new {StuffOwnerId = g.Key, loanid = (from t2 in g select t2.LoanId).Max()})
 on so.StuffOwnerId equals tmpLoan.StuffOwnerId
 into tmptmp  from tMaxLoan in tmptmp.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new {stuff, so, tmptmp}
```

Seems to generate a lot of subqueries as well.

I've tried the let keyworkd with:

```
from  tstuffOwner in StuffOwners 
let tloan = Loans.Where(p2 => tstuffOwner.StuffOwnerId == p2.StuffOwnerId).FirstOrDefault()
select new { qsdq = tstuffOwner, qsdsq= (int?) tloan.Status, kwk= (int?) tloan.UserId, kiwk=  tloan.ReturnDate  }
```

but the more info i get from tLoan, the longer the query gets with more subqueries

What would be the best way to achieve this?
Thanks